# Access the an objects keys and the index from an object in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to access the an object keys and the index from an object, **what is the best way to do this?**

this is data object:

```
d={KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"}
Object {KpiName: "KPI1", 1/1/2016: "85%", 1/2/2016: "87%"}
```

this is my for `1st` loop with output

```
for (var key in d) { console.log("d[\"key\"]: ", d[key]) }
d["key"]:  KPI1
 d["key"]:  85%
 d["key"]:  87%
```

this is what I want to achieve but I thought I could write it better

`2nd` for loop with output

```
i=1; for (var key in d) { console.log("d[\"key\"]: ", d[key]); console.log("i: ", i); i++}
d["key"]:  KPI1
i:  1
d["key"]:  85%
i:  2
d["key"]:  87%
i:  3
3
```

I thought I could write the for loop like this

```
for (var key, i  in d){...}
```

But it does not seem to work, maybe my `2nd` for loop achieves what I want but I am not sure if it the best code.

Comment: `for (var key in d) { console.log(key, d[key]) }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `for/in` loop, there is no better way to write this. You have to keep your own loop variable to count the iterations.

---

You *could* use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys first and then access their index either by using a `for` loop or using `forEach`, but I wouldn't call this "better", it's just a different way to go about it:

```js
var d = {KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"};

Object.keys(d).forEach(function(key, i) {
  console.log("d[\"key\"]: ", d[key]);
  console.log("i: ", i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get your question correctly, but you can use `Object.keys` with `forEach`:

```js
var d={KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"};

Object.keys(d).forEach(function(e, i){
  console.log("the key is: " + e + ", the value is: " + d[e] + ", the index is: " + i)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created some code that will print nicely what you are looking for. The trick is to use Object.keys because it passes the index for you. Here is a clean snippet of code that looks like it supports your use case:

```
var d = { KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"}

Object.keys(d).forEach(function (key, index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    console.log("  ",key,"        ",d[key])
    console.log("------------------------")
  } else {
    console.log( index + ". " + key + "          "+d[key]);
  }
});

// run then open console to view output

//    KpiName       KPI1
// ------------------------
// 1. 1/1/2016      85%
// 2. 1/2/2016      87%
```

I have provided a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/h9yw48bz/

Please shoot me a +1 if you find this to be a helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options as below to achieve this as below.

**Method 1**:

If you target only the modern browsers and not an old IE you can use `Object.keys` as below:

```js
var d = {KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"};
//var i = 0;
Object.keys(d).forEach(function(key, i){
   console.log('d["' + key + '"]: ' + d[key]); 
   console.log('index: ' + (i++).toString());
});
```

**Method 2**:

If you target old browsers as well, you can use the same one you did above with a minor change not to include any inherited object properties:

```js
var d = {KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"};
var i = 0;
for(var key in d) {
  if(d.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log('d["' + key + '"]: ' + d[key]); 
    console.log('index: ' + (i++).toString());
  }
}
```

**Method 3**:

Using Jquery

```js
var d = {KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"};
var i = 0;
$.each(d, function(key, value) {
  console.log('d["' + key + '"]: ' + value); 
  console.log('index: ' + (i++).toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Method 4**:

Using AngularJS

```js
var d = {KpiName:"KPI1",  '1/1/2016':"85%",  '1/2/2016':"87%"};
    var i = 0;
    angular.forEach(d, function(value, key) {
      console.log('d["' + key + '"]: ' + value); 
      console.log('index: ' + (i++).toString());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why did you mention jQuery and AngularJS, but not lodash, underscore, iter, or any other library that provides a way to iterate over values?